# How to create a new Project using the 'project.edit' Conduit API call

Tags: phabricator

Using Conduit, I would like to create a new project.
However, the Conduit documentation is rather cryptic, and the Transaction Types of 'project.edit' don't really give a clue on what transaction(s) are required/optional, to establish this.

I realize that there is a 'project.create' but is marked as to be deprecated.

Could any of you help me out here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically if you don't specify an `objectIdentifier`, `project.edit` will create a new project.  Probably the `name` is mandatory, I don't think that anything else is for projects.

Comment: OK, thanks. Somehow, in Conduit, I'm not able to get the syntax right. Would you have an example?

Comment: Found it: [{"type": "name", "value": "test"}]